# couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

When I run some kubernetes command in terminal, sometimes will shows warning:

```
> helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus \
    --namespace reddwarf-monitor \
    --set alertmanager.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2" \
    --set server.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2"
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/config
E1024 10:54:42.140774   19906 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:42.519186   19906 memcache.go:106] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:48.745209   19906 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:49.243689   19906 memcache.go:106] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:49.412790   19906 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:49.649522   19906 memcache.go:106] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:49.815406   19906 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:50.063481   19906 memcache.go:106] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:50.228200   19906 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:50.880837   19906 memcache.go:106] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E1024 10:54:51.170022   19906 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

this warning will not make the command going to failed but I am still want to fixed it. Why did this happen? This is the kubernetes version info:

```
[root@k8smasterone prometheus-server]# kubectl version
Client Version: v1.28.1
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.26.7
WARNING: version difference between client (1.28) and server (1.26) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

Comment: Is your metrics server running?